# error: no suitable method found for method ViewModelProviders.of(Fragment,Factory)

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-2

Trying to provde `ViewModel` via `ViewModelProviers.of()` to my activity.

My activity extends `AppCompatActivity` but I still see this error:

> error: no suitable method found for
>   of(StartActivity,StartViewModelFactory) method
>   ViewModelProviders.of(Fragment,Factory) is not applicable (argument
>   mismatch; StartActivity cannot be converted to Fragment) method
>   ViewModelProviders.of(FragmentActivity,Factory) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; StartActivity cannot be converted to
>   FragmentActivity)

Dependency Injection is provided with Dagger 2. Below is my Activity class StartActivity:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    StartViewModelFactory startViewModelFactory;
    StartModelView startModelView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startModelView = ViewModelProviders.of(this, startViewModelFactory).
                get(StartViewModel.class);

}
```

If I understand correctly you should be able to send in an activity in `ViewModelProviders.of()` method if they extend AppCompatActivity or Fragment. But I get this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using

```
   .get(StartModelView.class);
```

and not

```
 .get(StartViewModelFactory.class);
```

the factory provided to `of()` is used by android to generate an instance of your `ViewModel` subclass

Comment: Thanks, That is true. I added it in my code & this question. But the problem is still there. What could it persists? Could it have something to do with dependency injection?

Comment: It looks like you were correct. There was also another underlying problem with my modelviewfactory. I get a "uses uncecked or unsafe operations"  from this line  `@NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new StartModelView(getAllWalletsInteractor);
    }` DO you know why?

Comment: Should I add @SuppressWarning annotation to it?

Comment: Thanks again for the help!